How display nested array in Yajra datatable
I have an array that contains two sub-arrays, one called "version_anio"and another called "sedes",I pass the main array to Datatable and it only can display two values "escuela" and "curso" , since they are on the main array, how could I display both nested arrays on Yajra Datatable.I tried looping inside the columns with no success!

<!-- language: php -->
 <table class="table table-bordered data-table" id="tabla-resumen">
 <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Escuelas</th>
        <th>Curso</th>
         @foreach($data[0]->version_anio as $v_anio)      <---table headers load dynamic
        <th> {{ @$v_anio->name }} </th>
        @endforeach 
        
        {{-- @foreach($data[0]->sedes as $sede)
        <th> {{ @$sede->label }} </th>
        @endforeach --}} --
        {{-- <th>Total Inscritos</th> --}}
    </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>

 </tbody>
</table>

  //DATATABLE 
   var table = $('#tabla-resumen').DataTable({
    
    processing: false,
    serverSide: false,
    ajax: '{{ route("admin/resumen_anual") }}',
    dom: 'Bfltip',
  
    columns: [
        {data: 'escuela', name: 'escuela'},
        {data: 'curso', name: 'curso'},
      // $.each(version_anio, function(index, value) {  <---- looping failed
      // {data:'version_anio', name:'version_anio'},
      //  )},
       
    ],language: {
        url: '//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/2.1.4/i18n/es-MX.json',
        },
});



I found a non-dynamic solution , I get the results on the Datatable, but in case a new year_version(version_anio) appears it will stuck.
 //DATATABLE PRINCIPAL
var table = $('#tabla-resumen').DataTable({
    
    processing: false,
    serverSide: false,
    ajax: '{{ route("admin/resumen_anual") }}',
    dom: 'Bfltip',
   

    columns: [
        {data: 'escuela', name: 'escuela'},
        {data: 'curso', name: 'curso'},

        {data: 'version_anio.0.value'},  <--- I couldn't loop to deliver this
        {data: 'version_anio.1.value'},  <--
        {data: 'version_anio.2.value'},  <--
        {data: 'version_anio.3.value'},  <--
        {data: 'version_anio.4.value'},  <--
        {data: 'version_anio.5.value'},  <--
        {data: 'version_anio.6.value'},  <--
   
 
    ],language: {
        url: '//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/2.1.4/i18n/es-MX.json',
        },
});

